# special characters strange behavior in R

Tags: r, character-encoding, special-characters

I'm trying to work with these two webdings characters, `Ï` and `Ð`, but R is being difficult. When I try to print in the terminal in R-Studio, everything works fine:

```
print("Ï")
[1] "Ï"
> print("Ð")
[1] "Ð"
```

But if I save these two print statements to a file, and import with source, I get a different result:

```
source("test.r")
[1] "Ã\u008f"
[1] "Ã\u0090"
```

Another behavior which is strange to me, is if I try to save this character to a file:

```
f = "test.r"
cat("Ð", file = f)
```

The results i see in the file is `�`, even though, when I paste `Ð` in that same file, I can see it correctly.

What do I need to do to work with these characters in R?

Comment: are you on windows

Comment: note that `source` has an `encoding` argument, and `?cat` mentions `encodeString` for outputting encoding strings

Comment: "i see in the file" -- what are you using to see the file? this could also be that program's fault -- you might try a [hex editor](https://www.google.com/search?q=hex+editor&oq=hex+editor&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l7.1237j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) or using `readBin` from R

Comment: If you don't want to worry about encoding and it is just the odd letter here and there you can use Unicode escapes. These will print normally in R and will be readable as Ascii. Type`print("\u00cf")`in the console and you'll get `[1] "Ï"`

Comment: I'm on windows. I am using visual studio code. 
@AllanCameron will that work if I want to cat to a file?

Comment: @MichaelChirico Do you have a link that can explain how that encoding stuff works?

Comment: @Frank it's a very big topic... a classic reference is [this one](https://kunststube.net/encoding/)... though you should search around a bit to find a resource that fits your style & taste

Comment: I've also added the [tag:character-encoding] tag to your question, you could check the tag wiki for a bit more info as well